# How to conditionaly load components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an angular 2 app which every client can slightly modify before receiving the production version. Because the differences are not too big, all instances of app are build of the same source code. To achieve diffrent builds i use webpack with NormalModuleReplacementPlugin,

webpack.config

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/(.*)ENV(.*)/, function(resource) {
      var componentName = resource.request.slice(resource.request.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, resource.request.indexOf('ENV'));
      if(componentName in buildConfig){
          resource.request = resource.request.replace(/ENV/, buildConfig[componentName]);
      }
      else {
          resource.request = resource.request.replace(/ENV/, '');
      }
  })
```

import

```
import { RegisterComponent } from '../register/registerENV.component';
```

this works but also causes compiler and ide errors, which are preety annoying. So does anyone know better way to conditionaly build app with posibility to swap components and also not load unnecessary code into the bundle? 
English is not my mother tongue, please excuse any errors on my part.